# Proving that the norm of $f'(y)$ is attained at $\pm\frac{\nabla f(y)}{\|\nabla f(y)\|}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, inner-products

> Consider a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and a point $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\nabla f(y)\neq 0$. Prove that there exists an unit vector $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $$\sup\big\{|f'(y)v|;\, v\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{ and }\|v\|=1\big\}=|f'(y)x_0|=\|\nabla f(y)\|.\tag{A}$$
>   Moreover, there are only two possibilities for $x_0$:
>   $$x_0=\frac{\nabla f(y)}{\|\nabla f(y)\|}\qquad \text{ or }\qquad x_0=-\frac{\nabla f(y)}{\|\nabla f(y)\|}.\tag{B}$$

Possible solution for the first part:

Since the mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(v)=|f'(y)v|$ is continuous and the sphere $S=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n;\,\|v\|=1\}$ is compact, there exists an unit vector $x_0$ such that

$$|f'(y)x_0|=g(x_0)=\max\big\{g(v);\,v\in S\big\}=\sup\big\{|f'(y)v|;\, v\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{ and }\|v\|=1\big\}.\tag{1}$$

Let $u=\frac{\nabla f(y)}{\|\nabla f(y)\|}$. Then, from $(1)$,

$$|f'(y)x_0|\geq |f'(y)u|=\langle\nabla f(y),u\rangle=\|\nabla f(y)\|.\tag{2}$$

On the other hand, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$|f'(y)x_0|= \langle\nabla f(y),x_0\rangle\leq \|\nabla f(y)\|.\tag{3}$$

From $(1)$-$(3)$ we get $(A)$.

I'd like to know if the solution above is ok and how to get $(B)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $f$ as such.

You want to compute $\max \{ | u^T x | | \|x\| =  1 \}$. A maximiser exists because the boundary of the unit ball is compact and $x \mapsto | u^T x|$ is continuous.

Cauchy Schwarz gives $| u^T x | \le \|u\|$, and substitution shows that
$x={1 \over \|u\|} u$ attains this bound.

All that remains is to show uniqueness. Suppose $| u^T x | =\|u\|$ for
some unit length $\|x\|$. We can write $x = \lambda {1 \over \|u\|} u + w$, where $w \bot u$. It is easy to see that $\lambda^2+\|w\|^2 = 1$,
and $|u^T x| = |\lambda| \|u\|$, hence we must have $|\lambda| = 1$.

It follows that the maximising $x$ has the form $\pm {1 \over \|u\|} u$.